# El reciclerview sigue vacio a pensar de insertar productos

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Buenas estoy montando una lista de la compra con una base de datos DAO. El problema que tengo es que al añadir el producto me sigue apareciendo vacio el reciclerview.
Tengo tantas clases que no se que poneros. os dejo el dar de alta y si necesitais mas os pongo mas.

```
 public class AltaProductoFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditText et1, et2;
    private Button boton;
    private BaseDatosApp baseDatosApp;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alta_producto, container, false);
        et1 = root.findViewById(R.id.etProducto);
        et2 = root.findViewById(R.id.etCantidad);
        boton = root.findViewById(R.id.bAceptar);
        baseDatosApp = BaseDatosApp.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Producto p = new Producto(et1.getText().toString(), Double.parseDouble(et2.getText().toString()));
                new insertarProducto(baseDatosApp).execute(p);
                Snackbar.make(et2, "Se ha insertado un nuevo registro.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}

class insertarProducto extends AsyncTask<Producto, Void, Void> {
    private final BaseDatosApp database;

    public insertarProducto(BaseDatosApp database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Producto... params) {
        database.productoDAO().insertAll(params);
        return null;
    }
```

esta es la parte del viewModel

```
public class AltaProductoViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

public AltaProductoViewModel() {
    mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
    mText.setValue("This is dashboard fragment");
}

public LiveData<String> getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

}

Clase adaptadora

```
public class AdaptadorProducto extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private List<Producto> datos;
private Context contexto;
private int posicion;

public AdaptadorProducto(Context contexto, List<Producto> datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
    this.contexto = contexto;
}

public List<Producto> getDatos() {
    return datos;
}

public void setDatos(List<Producto> datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getPosicion() {
    return posicion;
}

public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
    this.posicion = posicion;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.producto_row, parent, false);
    ProductoViewHolder capital = new ProductoViewHolder(layout);
    return capital;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ProductoViewHolder) holder).bindProducto(datos.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            setPosicion(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datos.size();
}

public class ProductoViewHolder
        extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    private TextView tvProducto;
    private TextView tvCantidad;

    public ProductoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvProducto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProducto);
        tvCantidad = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCantidad);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
    }

        public void bindProducto(Producto p) {
        tvProducto.setText(p.getProducto());
        tvCantidad.setText(String.valueOf(p.getCantidad()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String resultado = "El producto seleccionado es: " + ((TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tvProducto)).getText() + " y hay que comprar " + ((TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCantidad)).getText() + " unidades.";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
        builder.setTitle("Información");
        builder.setMessage(resultado);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(contexto);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mimenu, menu);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pero creas el producto y se lo pasas a la base de datos, pero ¿dónde se lo pasas al Adapter del RecyclerView para que lo muestre?

Comment: Tengo una clase adaptadora claro, te la pongo

Comment: Sí, ya la veo, pero no veo donde llamas a refrescar la lista de productos que tienes guardada en el Adapter. Cuando das de alta un producto en la base de datos, o bien refrescas todos los productos desde la base de datos al Adapter o a la lista del Adapter le pasas el nuevo producto para que lo añada. El Adapter y la base de datos no se comunican. Es cosa tuya que lo hagan.

Comment: Y como hago eso?segun el profesor el codigo esta bien es asi

Comment: Tienes que pensar en el Adaptador como una clase que guarda los datos a mostrar en el ReciclerView y sabe como mostrarlos. Cuando Android quiera mostrar tu ReciclerView, tomará su lista interna de productos y los mostrará. Si desde fuera, en tu Activity, creas un nuevo producto, y solo se lo envías a la base de datos, el ReciclerView no se enteraría, con lo que pintará los datos que tenga en su lista interna nada más. Puedes implementar en el Adapter una función que reciba un producto, el nuevo, y que lo añada a la lista que guarda los productos y la llamas cuando insertas en la BD.

Comment: he usado   adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged(); en el insertar pero tiene un problema la aplicacion se cierra da error y luego al iniciarla si aparece

Comment: notifyDatasetChanged es la manera de, una vez has cambiado los datos de la lista interna del Adapter, pedir que lo repinte. Primero tienes que cambiar tu lista, sino repintará los mismos datos. Te funciona al reiniciar porque entiendo que leerás la base de datos completa y le pasarás la lista de productos al adapter. Depura para ver el motivo de la excepción.

Comment: vale el problema era que el adaptador tiraba a nulo, solucionado ahora el problema que tengo es que entre producto y producto el espacio es enorme tanto que tengo que hacer scroll para ver el siguiente.

Comment: eso ya no esta relacionado con el error de la pregunta, create una nueva pregunta con el xml del item, seguramente tenes mal puesto algun match_parent